# Do we need another 'as' before safely in "... as quickly and safely as possible"?

Tags: conjunctions

Is it correct to say:

> It is our mission to help you achieve your goals as quickly and safely as possible.

Or do we need to put another *as* before safely?

Comment: No, it is not needed. It is possible, but the sentence will be fine either way. I would probably not use it here.

Comment: @Cerberus I concur.  I was taught that one should seek to avoid repetition when writing.  While "... **as** quick and **as** safely **as** possible" is gramattically correct, the phrase is 50% "as."

Comment: @Lumberjack: Yeah, it's...iffy. There can be reasons.

Answer (score 2):

As Cerberus mentions, it is not needed. Either of these two sentences are valid:

> It is our mission to help you achieve your goals as quickly and safely as possible.
>
> It is our mission to help you achieve your goals as quickly and as safely as possible.

Which you choose is a personal preference. If you are writing for a publication or other organization with a formalized style guide you should ask your superior which is preferred.

Comment: Right. This is another case of conjunction reduction; the second _as_ can be retained for clarity or rhythm, as desired, or it can be deleted, as unnecessarily repeated matter.

Comment: Yooo long time no see! +1